# Get "use" namespaces by looking at the alias with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Suppose I have PHP code in a string variable. In that PHP code I have namespaces where some have an `alias`. I'd like to get the full namespace with regex by using the alias.

So for example, suppose I have the following code in a variable:

```
<?php
namespace Something;

use Foo\Bar\Baz as Name1, Foo\Bar\Qux as Name2;
use Foo\Bar\Grault, 
Foo\Bar\Quux;
use Foo\Bar\Corge as Name3;

class Test {
    // Class code ommited in this example
}
?>
```

I know the alias `Name1` is in the code. So i'd like to get the full namespace from that alias.

So in this case I'd like to get the following string back when I search for `Name1`:

```
[0] => Foo\Bar\Baz
```

And in the case of `Name3` I'd like to see:

```
[0] => Foo\Bar\Corge
```

The same should apply when I try to look forany other alias. Also, please note that sometimes that namespaces are separated by a comma and sometimes a newline occurs. The regex should be able to handle this.

I have the following so far, but it's not working the way I'd like. Especially when I search for `Name3`.

```
preg_match ( '~use(.*?)as +'.$alias.'(,|;)~s', $source, $matches )
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/a9GtTH

Anyone any idea how I could get the desired result?

Comment: You might get better results using the [`tokenizer`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php) extension or [`PHP_Parser`](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you can try:

```
$string = 'namespace Something;

use Foo\Bar\Baz as Name1, Foo\Bar\Qux as Name2;
use Foo\Bar\Grault, 
Foo\Bar\Quux;
use Foo\Bar\Corge as Name3;';

$array_of_patterns = array('Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3');

foreach ($array_of_patterns AS $pattern) {

    preg_match('~\b([A-Z\\\]+)(?= as '.$pattern.')~i', $string, $matches);
    print "\n".$pattern.": ".$matches[0];

}
```

This outputs:

```
Name1: Foo\Bar\Baz
Name2: Foo\Bar\Qux
Name3: Foo\Bar\Corge
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for `Name1` and `Name3`, it doesn't handle names after a comma...:

```
<?php

  $source = "
    <?php

      namespace Something;

      use Foo\Bar\Baz as Name1, Foo\Bar\Qux as Name2;
      use Foo\Bar\Grault,
      Foo\Bar\Quux;
      use Foo\Bar\Corge as Name3;

      class Test {
          // Class code ommited in this example
      }
    ?>
  ";

  $alias = 'Name1'; # 'Name1' / 'Name2' / 'Name3'
  preg_match('/use\s+(.*?)\s+as\s+'.$alias.'\s*[,;].*/', $source, $matches);
  print $matches[1];
?>
```